# Magento API V2 - add an additional attribute to API response

Tags: api, magento, soap

I'm using the Magento API V2.

When I call **salesOrderCreditmemoInfo**, I get a response with the credit memo details and a list of the products associated with the order.

But in the list of product items there is no **product_type** attribute.

I want to manually edit the response to add this attribute.

I tried editing:
**app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\Api.php**

And replaced:

```
public function info($creditmemoIncrementId)
{
    ...
    $result['items'] = array();
    foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $result['items'][] = $this->_getAttributes($item, 'creditmemo_item');
    }
```

With the following - (basically appending an extra attribute to the array):

```
 public function info($creditmemoIncrementId)
    {
      ...
    $result['items'] = array();
    foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product_type = '1'; //test value to check if works
            $attribs = $this->_getAttributes($item, 'creditmemo_item');
            $attribs['product_type'] = $product_type;

            $result['items'][] = $attribs;
        }
```

When I do mage::log($result), the extra attribute seems to be added correctly to the array.
(also indicating that this function is the one getting called) 
But it has no impact on the actual API response.

Am I totally looking in the wrong place or is there something else I need to update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since You were using SOAP V2, you should *update the* `wsdl.xml` *to get the output*.

For your case it is **product_type** and *refresh cache on server*. **/tmp** to load the new `wsdl.xml` that already updated. don't forget to go to **System -> Cache Management** clear all cache.

Comment: @Josua could you please suggest some solution for this problem                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811307/get-simple-product-sku-and-qty-using-salesorderinfo-of-soap-api-in-magento