# How to get the returned values as stdClass object

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am having following code to override V2.php

```
class Test_Sales_Model_Order_Api_V2 extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api_V2
{
    public function info($orderIncrementId)
    {  
        $result = parent::info( $orderIncrementId ); 
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);       
        $orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();

        $skuQtyArray = array();
        foreach ($orderItems as $item)
        {
              $product_id = $item->product_id;
             $product_sku = $item->sku;
                 $item_id = $item->getItemId();     
            $tax_percent = $item->gettaxPercent();                      
            $product_qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();                      

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $product_sku);              
            $productType=$product->getTypeID();
            if($productType=='simple')
            {                                           
                    $skuQtVal = $product_sku."=".$item_id;
                    $skuQtyArray[] = $skuQtVal;                                 
            }
        }

    $result['simple_product_skus'] = array_unique($skuQtyArray);         

    return $result; 
    }
    
}
```

Now I am accessing this as

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('testuser', 'testuser');

$result = $client ->salesOrderInfo($session, '100000026'); 
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output is like

```
 stdClass Object
 (
        ------
        ------
        ------

     [status_history] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [parent_id] => 72
                [created_at] => 2013-11-08 14:42:11
                [is_customer_notified] => 1
                [status] => pending
            )

    )

            [simple_product_skus] => Array
            (
                [0] => ASL-B346-67-64-98=155=166=1.0000=0.0000
                [1] => ASL-B346-67-64-98=156=116=1.0000=0.0000
            )
    
 )
```

I want simple_product_skus as stdClass Object Like I am getting status_history .

How can I get this please help.

Comment: Do you mean you want status_history to be a stdClass object instead of an Array?

Comment: @Michael J. Anderson  I want [simple_product_skus] as stdClass Object, Like I am getting for the status_history.

Comment: http://www.kathirvel.com/php-convert-or-cast-array-to-object-object-to-array/

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano I did like (object)array_unique($skuQtyArray); as suggested in the answer and getting the error

Comment: Did you try simple call only one item and work with it isolated (convert to array and back to object)
$result->simple_product_skus or $result = (array)$result[simple_product_skus]?

Comment: @Muk when the array of status_history assigned?

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano  [status_history] comes when I use $result = $client ->salesOrderInfo($session, '100000026');  using soap api in magento to get the orders details.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you want:

```
$result['simple_product_skus'] = (object)array_unique($skuQtyArray);
```

This is type casting the array into a standard php object.

Comment: JAnderson I am getting Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to undefined function object()

Comment: Strange that it's a SOAP exception. At that point in the code you've already received a response from your requests, correct? Can you post more details?

Comment: I am getting proper values in array_unique($skuQtyArray).But conversion to object is problem